# Как сохранить данные формы между страницами?

Tags: javascript

Некий сайт 10 страниц.
Имеется почтовая форма "php" (Ф.И.О. , тел. , текст, Отправить).

Теперь вопрос:

1. Вызвал форму внес № телефона (пока не отправил)
2. Перешёл на другие страницы.
3. Вернулся на почтовую форму, а там моего № телефона уже нет (не сохранилось).

Как сделать, чтобы внесенная запись (в данном случае № телефона) не исчезла до отправки на почту?

Comment: 1) Постарайтесь в будущем оформлять вопрос более читабельно. 2) Здесь не биржа, на заказ работы не делают. 3) php тут не при чём, это надо делать на стороне клиента.

Answer (score 3):

При вводе или при смене фокуса с элемента ввода сохранять данные куда-нить локально (в Local Storage, например).

При повторном заходе на страницу брать оттуда данные и заносить в поля в форме.

При отправке очищать эти поля в Local Storage.